# RNNCell with output and state of different sizes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm building a model with a `keras.layers.GRU` layer with `return_sequences=True`. However, in addition to the output at each timestamp, I want the Layer to return two extra outputs: the activations of the forget and reset gates at each timestamp.

To achieve this, I created

(1) a modified copy of `keras.layers.GRUCell` where `return h, [h]` is replaced by `return K.concatenate([h, z, r]), [h]`, and

(2) a modified copy of `keras.layers.GRU`, where `self.output_size = self.units` is replaced by `self.output_size = self.units * 3`, and the return statement in `call()`,

```
return super(GRU, self).call(
    inputs, mask=mask, training=training, initial_state=initial_state)
```

is replaced by

```
return (rnn_output[:, :, :self.cell.units],
        rnn_output[:, :, self.cell.units:self.cell.units * 2],
        rnn_output[:, :, self.cell.units * 2:self.cell.units * 3])
```

When trying to run this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gru_with_gates.py", line 245, in <module>
    main()
  File "gru_with_gates.py", line 107, in main
    rnn_output = GRUCellWithGates.GRU(cfg.OUTPUT_DIM, return_sequences=True)(full_feature_vector)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 532, in __call__
    return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 457, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File ".../GRUCellWithGates.py", line 467, in call
    initial_state=initial_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 649, in call
    input_length=timesteps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 3011, in rnn
    maximum_iterations=input_length)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 3209, in while_loop
    result = loop_context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2941, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2878, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2974, in _step
    output = tf.where(tiled_mask_t, output, states[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2607, in where
    return gen_math_ops.select(condition=condition, x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 6699, in select
    "Select", condition=condition, t=x, e=y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1756, in __init__
    control_input_ops)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1592, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 768 and 256. Shapes are [?,768] and [?,256]. for 'gru_1/while/Select' (op: 'Select') with input shapes: [?,?], [?,768], [?,256].
```

The issue seems to be [this line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2974) in keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py, which assumes that the output and state should be of the same size:

`output = tf.where(tiled_mask_t, output, states[0])`

However, this assumption is not contained in the specification of a cell in https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L237. Actually, since the cell must implement two different attributes `state_size` and `output_size`, this shouldn't be a problem.

1) Did I get this correctly?

2) If so, is there any way I can work around this limitation?

3) Would there be a better/easier way to get the forget and reset gate activations from a GRU layer?

Comment: Apparently this was a known issue that was fixed around a month ago: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/5a8f346e64cb432a445002230246ee042dbc278b#diff-a18b8c6a1191d6f49303e0d599ca8c37

Questions 2) and 3) above remain: can you see any way I could work around this limitation without using the fix above? Is this the best way to get the gate activations as an output?

Comment: First comments (before thinking deeply). It won't be necessary to have a changed `GRU`. (It's just a `RNN(GRUCell)`). So, you should probably only create a custom `GRUCell` and also use a `RNN(GRUCell)`.

Comment: You might try to return the things you want in the list of states: `return h, [h,z,r]`. And use `return_states=True` in the layer. (But I didn't check if the states are returned per step in this case)

Comment: @DanielMöller if I return these values in the state vector, then I think the RNN will use them in the next timestep, leading to different results. I want to ensure that I get the same results, regardless of whether or not the layer outputs the gate activations.

Comment: I checked, the states are not returned per step... but the layer is immune to that in the line`h_tm1 = states[0]`

Comment: My tests show that older versions cannot handle different sizes well indeed.... in a new Keras version, you just need `self.output_size=3*units` in the cell's `__init__` method. (You don't need a changed GRU, just a `RNN(NewGRUCell(units), return_sequences=True)`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @DanielMöller. Two questions/clarifications: 
(1) by "older versions", you mean up to the latest release, 2.2.4, right? If so, I would need to use a version cloned from the GitHub repo to handle this.
(2) I'm using a modified GRU layer just because I want the layer output tensor to be split into three layer outputs, so that I avoid having to do this splitting at the model level.

Comment: I don't know which version, but one I had in my PC calculates the output features as units, and the version currently available in Kaggle.com calculates 3*units.